# Help with my .htaccess file

Tags: file, .htaccess

I don't know why this is happening but I can access html pages WITHOUT typing in the .html extension. This is causing duplicate content.

Example: If you type in

`http://www.math-aids.com/Addition/Single_Digit`will go to the

`http://www.math-aids.com/Addition/Single_Digit.html` file.

This is happening for all of my files.

I do not want that to happen. If someone does not type in the .html for a file, then I want it to return a 404 error " file not found ".

How can I fix this? I completely removed the .htaccess file and it still happens.

Here is my .htaccess file.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
rewriteengine on
RewriteBase /

### re-direct IP address to www
### re-direct non-www to www
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.math-aids.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.math-aids.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L] 

### re-direct index.html to root / ###
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.html?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [R=301,L]

### re-direct index.php to root / ###
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct default.html to root / ###
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/default\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)default\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct home.html to root / ###
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\/home\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)home\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

### re-direct errors to error page
ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix this? I completely removed the .htaccess file and it still happens.

This is because the `.htaccess` file you posted doesn't append `.html` suffixes to anything. It must be another `.htaccess` file or something in your main Apache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have "Options MultiViews" somewhere in your Apache configuration (not the .htaccess file).

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews